# How to get float value with SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, casting, reader

In my database, I have NextStatDistanceTime value as a float. When "`float time = reader.GetFloat(0);`" line excecuted, it gives an error of

> system invalid cast exception

How can I get float value from sql command in this code?

Here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"<myconnectionstring>"))
{
    float totaltime = 0;
    for (int i = startStationIndex; i < endStationIndex; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT NextStatDistanceTime FROM [MetroDatabase].[dbo].[MetroStation] WHERE StationIndex = " + i + "", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    float time = reader.GetFloat(0);
                    totaltime = totaltime + time;
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }                        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the type in the database?

Comment: @JonSkeet he has mentioned it, its "float" in database.

Comment: @RanjitSingh: Whoops, missed that. In that case I'd really expect it to be fine... My guess is that it isn't *really* a float in the database. It would be interesting to know the result of calling `reader.GetValue(0)` - what type is that?

Comment: As an aside, you should *immediately* start using parameterized SQL.

Comment: Oh, and why not get the database to sum the values for you? It seems odd to fetch all the values, just to add them up...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's time for a little table, I think.

| T-SQL type name | .NET equivalent | C# type name | `DataReader` method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `FLOAT` | `System.Double` | `double` | `IDataReader.GetDouble()` |
| `REAL` | `System.Single` | `float` | `IDataReader.GetFloat()` |

Note that `GetFloat` has the wrong name -- it should be `GetSingle`, because `float` is a C#-specific name. It makes no sense in VB.NET, for example.

So, if your database column is of type `FLOAT`, read it using `GetDouble`, not `GetFloat`. The data reader methods do *not* perform conversions; there is a generic `GetValue` method to get the value as an `object` that you can then convert further.

Incidentally, this is not the only subtlety -- the .NET floating-point types support [denormalized values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), whereas the T-SQL types do not, so it is possible to have floating-point numbers in your .NET code that can't be successfully stored in the database, even if the types match.

Comment: You can find the table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(v=sql.130).aspx) ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: that's a subtly different table because it describes the mapping to the ADO.NET SQL-specific types as well. `SqlSingle` isn't the same as `System.Single`. I could include it in my table for completeness, but there's rarely a need to use these types unless there's no corresponding .NET system type (like `SqlGeography`). But, yes, this is another layer of conversions to be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

As you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(v=sql.130).aspx) a sql-server float maps to a .NET double, so you need to use [`GetDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdouble(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
double totaltime = 0;  // necessary, double is wider than float
// ...

while (reader.Read())
{
    double time = reader.GetDouble(0);
    totaltime = totaltime + time;
    // conn.Close(); no, not in this loop, should be closed in the finally or via using-statement
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that Database is returning double value, try getting  it as `Double` and convert it `float` (if required).

```
float time= (float) reader.GetDouble(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
float time = float.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
```

also note (though not related with your Q) that you don't need to run

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (reader.Read())
 {
     object initialTime = reader["NextStatDistanceTime"];
     float time;
     float.TryParse(initialTime.ToString(), out time);

     totaltime = totaltime + time;
     conn.Close();
 }
```

Try this, this will get the time from the Database then convert it to a float, you can just put the `reader["NextStatDistanceTime]` in the tryparse if you want but to make it clearer i have done it like this.

Any issues let me know

Comment: @TimSchmelter explain?

Comment: See for example @Hari Prasad's answer. No need for that work around.

Comment: It's not just unnecessary, but it's potentially dangerous. Suppose it's coming back from the database as a string already, using `.` as the decimal separator, but the OP is using a culture which uses `,` as the decimal separator...

Comment: @RenéVogt and Tim Schmelter Can you explain why it is an unnecessary workaround?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, that makes sense, it wouldnt be able to be converted into a float otherwise, and would probably have to validate it before using it as a float to check if it contains a ',' or something along those lines

Comment: @Brendon: Fundamentally, this is an unnecessary conversion to and then from string. Such conversions should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok thank you, I am unfamiliar with the .GetDouble they are using which is the reason to the answer i have made... I will do some research on those and use them in my future code

Comment: @Brendon: because you accept the fact that OP doesn't know that floats are mapped to `double` and provide workaround with string conversions. That might work in this case, but could cause other issues (in future). String conversions are always vulnerable to localization issues(f.e. one culture uses colon the  other comma as decimal separator). It's also not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
convert.ToSingle(reader["NextStatDistanceTime"])
```

or do

```
double value = (double)reader["NextStatDistanceTime"]
```

Float of sql is equivalent to double of c#, you can see the similar mapping [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Probably is precision mismatch between database type and c# type.
Try cast like `(float)reader.GetDouble(0);`