# Better way to parse nullable double value from sql reader

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to parse SqlDecimal from SqlDataReader to double than this?

```
class test {
    public double? Qte { get; set; }
}

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.executeReader();
reader.Read();

test t = new test() {
    Qte = (reader["DL_Qte"] == DBNull.Value) ? (double?)null : double.Parse(reader["DL_Qte"].ToString())
}
```

Comment: Whats `reader`? If it's a `SqlDataReader` you relaise it has a [`GetDouble` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdouble(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: reader is SqlDataReader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get float value with SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344167/how-to-get-float-value-with-sqldatareader)

Comment: If it's a decimal or money in database, why don't you store it as decimal in your model?

Comment: I can't change my model from <double?> to <decimal?>

Answer (score 3):

Here's the way I'd do it:

```
double d = reader.GetFieldValue<double>(reader.GetOrdinal("DL_Qte"));
```

`GetFieldValue<T>` is only available since .NET 4.5, so you can also do this:

```
double d = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("DL_Qte"));
```

**EDIT:**

To address the issue with nullable and DB null you're having, you could do something like this:

```
int columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("DL_Qte");

double? d = !reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex) ? 
    reader.GetFieldValue<double>(columnIndex) : new double?();
```

Comment: I get a System.InvalidCastException Qte is nullable (double?)

Comment: Then use `double?` instead of `double`.

Comment: I get System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException This method cannot be called on null values

Comment: @ScottChamberlain -- I've run into trouble in the past with just null when using a ternary operator.  I can't remember in what context or what happened, but it introduced a bug, and the solution was using this approach, which I've used ever since.

Comment: I think I know the quirk you are talking about and I think it only applies when the true condition of the operator is `null` and it can't infer the type, the false condition does not have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a decimal or money in database, why don't you store it as decimal in your model? You should also not parse a `decimal` to `string` and then to `double`, use the [right method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class Test {
    public decimal? Qte { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
int columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("DL_Qte");
decimal? qte = null;
if(!reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
    qte = reader.GetDecimal(columnIndex);  // <----- !!!
Test t = new Test { Qte = qte };
```