# Cast Object to Float from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm retrieving some data with a `SqlDataReader` and trying to convert one of these objects to a float (the same as its data type in the database).

What I have:

```
u.unitid = (float)Convert.ToSingle((reader["UNITID"]));
```

This returns a "0" for every unitid.

Comment: have you tried converting it directly to float instead of first converting it tosingle then casting it to float?

Comment: It makes no sense to case the result of `ToSingle` to `float` since it is already a `float`.  Have you tried the `reader.GetFloat()` method?  What is the column type of `UNITED` in the database?

Comment: ToSingle already gives a float, why second cast? Also, what are the values of unitid?

Comment: Did you know DataReaders have a number of typed `Getxxxx` methods such as `GetSingle()`?  If it always returns 0 for any row consider that the query may be wrong etc

Comment: `Single` is the CLR name that C# aliases as `float`. They are the same, the cast is not necessary.

Comment: Can you run this in a step-thru debugger with `object o = reader["UNITID"];` on one line and `u.unitid = Convert.ToSingle(o);` on the next line.  That way you can see what the returned value actually is before converting.

Comment: The values of UNITID are 6-8 digit integers. It's datatype in database and in model is float.

Comment: did you try float.Parse(reader["UNITID"].ToString());?

Comment: [The SQL type `FLOAT` corresponds to the .NET `Double` data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37344567/4137916), and should be read using `.GetDouble()`. That said, `Convert` should still work if `UNITID` really holds non-zero doubles.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you! GetDouble worked.